# SOLR / LUCENE how to expand list into multi-valued fields?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am indexing from a RDBMS. I have a column in a table with pipe separated values, and upon indexing I would like to transform these values into multi-valued fields. For example,

```
ColumnA (From RDBMS)
---------------------
apple|orange|banana
```

I want to transform this to:

```
SOLR Index
------------
Fruit=apple
Fruit=orange
Fruit=banana
```

Answer (score 6):

I you use a RegexTransformer, you can specify a splitBy="|"

```
<field column="Fruit" splitBy="|" sourceColName="ColumnA"/>
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer